# Error using vaex: blake3.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multithreading'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vaex

When I use `vaex` as follows:

```
for i, df in enumerate(vaex.from_csv('cars.csv', convert=True,chunk_size=100_000)):
            print(df.info())
```

I get an error:

```
blake3.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multithreading'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this by reinstalling an older blake3 version.

```
pip install blake3==0.2.1
```